# What are some general troubleshooting tips for React Native projects?

Tags: react-native

I keep running into unusual issues with my React Native builds. My team members don't seem to run into the same issues I experience. Most of the time the issues are solved with general troubleshooting tasks. What are some troubleshooting processes that can help eliminate issues with running a React Native application?

Mostly using this post as a note to self. Feel free to join the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some quick things to do that can eliminate most unusual issues that tend to crop up when developing with React Native:

- Restart the application
- Make sure all dependencies are running (things like backend servers).
- Yarn install, you might be missing a package.
- Delete `node_modules`. When you use Yarn install, it doesn't remove old or corrupted versions. Doing a clean install in this way can help odd dependency issues.
- Restart your computer. Another application can (though unlikely) interfere with your project.

Thank you for reading. I'm mostly using this post as a note to self. I hope someone else can learn from me hitting my head against a wall.